# rename file is not working on php

Tags: php, rename

Hi i have problem with this code 
with the code i can change whole my folder file to number like 1.mp4 2.mp4 ect...

i test the code and i print the name of the file from it and every thing is right 
but rename function is not working 
this is my code

```
$dir = opendir('.');

$i = 1;

// loop through all the files in the directory
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{


    // if the extension is '.mp4'
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'mp4')
    {
 echo $file ;

        // do the rename based on the current iteration
        $newName = $i . '.mp4';
        rename($file, $newName);

        // increase for the next loop
        $i++;
    }
}

// close the directory handle
closedir($dir);

?>
```

what is the problem now ?

***NEW iNFO***

```
i tried the code inside my localhost and it's work but it's not working inside the server
```

Comment: `$i` should be a string. `$i='1';`

Comment: yes i initialize it in the  second line

Comment: `$i = 1;` is not `$i='1';`

Comment: why i need to do that  ?? ? 
it's number not string and i need to increase  it    
the problem not from what are you speaking about

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to use [glob()](http://php.net/glob)

```
foreach(glob(__DIR__ . '/*.mp4') as $key => $file) {
  if(!rename($file, __DIR__ . '/' . ($key + 1) . '.mp4')) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to write to '. $file);
  }
}
```

I'll hazard a guess it's a write permissions issue though - I don't see anything directly wrong with the script.

Comment: yes the problem is permesiion problem i tried your code but nothing changed 
and i tried your code and my code inside localhost they are working100%

Comment: but i dont know what is the problem with the permission

Comment: Works locally but not on the server?  Try opening a shell and running PHP off the command line to do this operation.  PHP runs with the webserver daemon's permissions unless it is ran as a CLI script, in which case it will have the permissions of the user executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the real path can help:

$file = realpath($filename);

but it sounds like it could be a permissions issue or an SELinux issue also. You will need apache to be the group on the files in question, and the files should be writeable by the group.

Also, if you have SELinux enabled, you will need to use

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/images/folder(/.*)?"

and

restorecon -R -v /path/to/images/folder